# XML Reading in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a requirement where I have to read a tag value in xml. This tag is not getting repeated in xml.

I have tried below codes:

```
file_name ="ip_20180250_53638_[03-CORP].kfx.xml"
'msgbox  "D:\Sonam\"& file_name

set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.async = "false"
objXML.load("D:\Sonam\"& file_name)
Set Root = objXML.documentElement
'Set Root = objXML.TAX_SUM

For Each x In Root.childNodes

 if x.nodename="DT-VEROVA" then
    value=x.text
    msgbox value
 end if
Next
```

Comment: XML as below(No tag is empty, I have deleted the value)

Comment: can you paste sample xml?